# Postgres Query Optimization, high cost functions

Tags: postgresql, optimization, postgresql-performance

Currently I'm working with a postgres table that looks like this (postgres12)

```sql
create table if not exists asset (
  id text,
  symbol text not null,
  name text not null
  primary key (id)
);
create table if not exists latest_value (
  timestamp bigint,
  asset text,
  price decimal null,
  market_cap decimal null,
  primary key (asset),
  foreign key (asset)
    references asset (id)
    on delete cascade
);
create table if not exists value_aggregation (
  context aggregation_context,
  timestamp bigint,
  asset text,
  price jsonb null,
  market_cap jsonb null,
  primary key (context, timestamp, asset),
  foreign key (asset)
      references asset (id)
      on delete cascade
) partition by list (context);

create table if not exists value_aggregation_hour
partition of value_aggregation
for values in ('hour');

create index if not exists value_aggregation_timestamp_index
  on value_aggregation using brin(timestamp)
  with (autosummarize=true);
```

The table `value_aggregation_hour` has approximately 2 million rows.
The `price` column consists of a jsonb with attributes like open, close, avg

Now the problem:

The following query takes way too long.

```sql
WITH base_table AS
  (SELECT asset, timestamp, market_cap, price
  FROM latest_value
  ORDER BY market_cap DESC
  LIMIT 50
  OFFSET 0)
SELECT asset.name, asset.symbol, asset.id, asset.market_data, asset.meta_data, timestamp, market_cap, price, spark.sparkline
FROM base_table LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT asset, array_agg(CAST(price->>'open' AS decimal) ORDER BY timestamp ASC) AS sparkline
  FROM value_aggregation
  WHERE context = 'hour'
  AND timestamp > extract(epoch from (now() - INTERVAL '7d'))
  AND asset IN (
    SELECT asset
    FROM base_table)
GROUP BY asset
) spark ON base_table.asset = spark.asset
INNER JOIN asset ON base_table.asset = asset.id;
```

The resulting queryplan looks like this:

```
Merge Left Join  (cost=234610.64..234774.05 rows=494 width=1740) (actual time=9173.660..9176.986 rows=50 loops=1)
  Merge Cond: (base_table.asset = value_aggregation_hour.asset)
  CTE base_table
    ->  Limit  (cost=140.48..140.61 rows=50 width=71) (actual time=2.040..2.051 rows=50 loops=1)
          ->  Sort  (cost=140.48..145.48 rows=2001 width=71) (actual time=2.039..2.043 rows=50 loops=1)
                Sort Key: latest_value.market_cap DESC
                Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 36kB
                ->  Seq Scan on latest_value  (cost=0.00..74.01 rows=2001 width=71) (actual time=0.011..0.536 rows=2001 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=377.41..377.54 rows=50 width=1740) (actual time=2.582..2.660 rows=50 loops=1)
        Sort Key: base_table.asset
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 127kB
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.28..376.00 rows=50 width=1740) (actual time=2.071..2.434 rows=50 loops=1)
              ->  CTE Scan on base_table  (cost=0.00..1.00 rows=50 width=232) (actual time=2.042..2.068 rows=50 loops=1)
              ->  Index Scan using asset_pkey on asset  (cost=0.28..7.50 rows=1 width=1508) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=1 loops=50)
                    Index Cond: (id = base_table.asset)
  ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=234092.62..234226.12 rows=1977 width=54) (actual time=9171.070..9174.268 rows=15 loops=1)
        Group Key: value_aggregation_hour.asset
        ->  Sort  (cost=234092.62..234110.75 rows=7253 width=203) (actual time=9167.909..9168.235 rows=2501 loops=1)
              Sort Key: value_aggregation_hour.asset
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 761kB
              ->  Hash Semi Join  (cost=1.62..233627.54 rows=7253 width=203) (actual time=8985.832..9163.859 rows=2501 loops=1)
                    Hash Cond: (value_aggregation_hour.asset = base_table_1.asset)
                    ->  Seq Scan on value_aggregation_hour  (cost=0.00..232792.39 rows=286795 width=203) (actual time=8983.255..9112.164 rows=304163 loops=1)
                          Filter: ((\"timestamp\" > '1597855853329'::bigint) AND (context = 'hour'::aggregation_context))
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 2228311
                    ->  Hash  (cost=1.00..1.00 rows=50 width=32) (actual time=0.032..0.032 rows=50 loops=1)
                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 11kB
                          ->  CTE Scan on base_table base_table_1  (cost=0.00..1.00 rows=50 width=32) (actual time=0.004..0.014 rows=50 loops=1)
Planning Time: 1.203 ms
Execution Time: 9177.185 ms
```

I noticed that the query planner does not use the created index on `value_aggregation_hour` and was wondering why. After some googling I disabled the seqscan during debugging, executed the query again with `explain analyze` and then the following query plan came out:

```
Merge Left Join  (cost=10000237612.82..10000237776.37 rows=494 width=1740) (actual time=212.122..215.857 rows=50 loops=1)
  Merge Cond: (base_table.asset = value_aggregation_hour.asset)
  CTE base_table
    ->  Limit  (cost=10000000140.48..10000000140.61 rows=50 width=71) (actual time=1.745..1.756 rows=50 loops=1)
          ->  Sort  (cost=10000000140.48..10000000145.48 rows=2001 width=71) (actual time=1.744..1.748 rows=50 loops=1)
                Sort Key: latest_value.market_cap DESC
                Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 36kB
                ->  Seq Scan on latest_value  (cost=10000000000.00..10000000074.01 rows=2001 width=71) (actual time=0.006..0.555 rows=2001 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=377.41..377.54 rows=50 width=1740) (actual time=2.240..2.250 rows=50 loops=1)
        Sort Key: base_table.asset
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 127kB
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.28..376.00 rows=50 width=1740) (actual time=1.771..2.090 rows=50 loops=1)
              ->  CTE Scan on base_table  (cost=0.00..1.00 rows=50 width=232) (actual time=1.746..1.773 rows=50 loops=1)
              ->  Index Scan using asset_pkey on asset  (cost=0.28..7.50 rows=1 width=1508) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=1 loops=50)
                    Index Cond: (id = base_table.asset)
  ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=237094.80..237228.44 rows=1977 width=54) (actual time=209.877..213.542 rows=15 loops=1)
        Group Key: value_aggregation_hour.asset
        ->  Sort  (cost=237094.80..237112.96 rows=7262 width=203) (actual time=209.618..210.065 rows=2501 loops=1)
              Sort Key: value_aggregation_hour.asset
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 761kB
              ->  Hash Semi Join  (cost=111.95..236629.08 rows=7262 width=203) (actual time=0.868..206.008 rows=2501 loops=1)
                    Hash Cond: (value_aggregation_hour.asset = base_table_1.asset)
                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on value_aggregation_hour  (cost=110.32..235792.92 rows=287144 width=203) (actual time=0.758..155.291 rows=304163 loops=1)
                          Recheck Cond: (\"timestamp\" > '1597855085099'::bigint)
                          Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 215
                          Filter: (context = 'hour'::aggregation_context)
                          Heap Blocks: lossy=23414
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on value_aggregation_hour_timestamp_idx  (cost=0.00..38.54 rows=287851 width=0) (actual time=0.698..0.698 rows=234240 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: (\"timestamp\" > '1597855085099'::bigint)
                    ->  Hash  (cost=1.00..1.00 rows=50 width=32) (actual time=0.025..0.025 rows=50 loops=1)
                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 11kB
                          ->  CTE Scan on base_table base_table_1  (cost=0.00..1.00 rows=50 width=32) (actual time=0.001..0.007 rows=50 loops=1)
Planning Time: 1.532 ms
Execution Time: 216.114 ms
```

The end costs are pretty high, but I assume that is because there is no index on `latest_value` and he needs to use a seqscan(off = ultra high costs?). 
But now he uses the index of `value_aggregation_hour` and it is waaaay faster. 
As disabling seqscan is not a valid option except for debugging, how can I make this work properly? Can I optimize the query? Maybe change something of the BRIN, so he uses that instead of a seqscan? 
Or would a parameter tuning be more adequate, so the cost functions get calculated differently?
I'm using an RDS postgres instance db.t3.small with the default config.

**Update #1**:
Removing the `AND asset IN (...)` (redundant?) subquery increases the execution time by a second(seqscan on), heres the resulting query plan:

```
Merge Left Join  (cost=285605.54..289542.19 rows=494 width=1589) (actual time=10213.724..10561.884 rows=50 loops=1)"
  Merge Cond: (latest_value.asset = value_aggregation_hour.asset)"
  ->  Sort  (cost=517.65..517.77 rows=50 width=1579) (actual time=2.315..2.347 rows=50 loops=1)"
        Sort Key: latest_value.asset"
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 127kB"
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=140.89..516.24 rows=50 width=1579) (actual time=1.646..2.160 rows=50 loops=1)"
              ->  Limit  (cost=140.61..140.74 rows=50 width=71) (actual time=1.623..1.634 rows=50 loops=1)"
                    ->  Sort  (cost=140.61..145.62 rows=2004 width=71) (actual time=1.622..1.626 rows=50 loops=1)"
                          Sort Key: latest_value.market_cap DESC"
                          Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 36kB"
                          ->  Seq Scan on latest_value  (cost=0.00..74.04 rows=2004 width=71) (actual time=0.006..0.507 rows=2004 loops=1)"
              ->  Index Scan using asset_pkey on asset  (cost=0.28..7.50 rows=1 width=1508) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=1 loops=50)"
                    Index Cond: (id = latest_value.asset)"
  ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=285087.89..288994.63 rows=1977 width=54) (actual time=10196.939..10558.723 rows=1795 loops=1)"
        Group Key: value_aggregation_hour.asset"
        ->  Sort  (cost=285087.89..285734.90 rows=258802 width=203) (actual time=10196.652..10291.799 rows=295051 loops=1)"
              Sort Key: value_aggregation_hour.asset"
              Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 66000kB"
              ->  Seq Scan on value_aggregation_hour  (cost=0.00..236164.67 rows=258802 width=203) (actual time=8901.696..9056.748 rows=304558 loops=1)"
                    Filter: ((\"timestamp\" > '1597925634239'::bigint) AND (context = 'hour'::aggregation_context))"
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 2264599"
Planning Time: 1.149 ms"
Execution Time: 10573.183 ms"
```

**Update #2:**

changing the query to a_horse_with_no_name left join lateral suggestion resulted in:

```
Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=141.45..576626.74 rows=6550 width=1589) (actual time=68.291..1313.768 rows=50 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=140.89..516.24 rows=50 width=1579) (actual time=3.897..5.104 rows=50 loops=1)
        ->  Limit  (cost=140.61..140.74 rows=50 width=71) (actual time=3.855..3.931 rows=50 loops=1)
              ->  Sort  (cost=140.61..145.62 rows=2004 width=71) (actual time=3.853..3.900 rows=50 loops=1)
                    Sort Key: latest_value.market_cap DESC
                    Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 37kB
                    ->  Seq Scan on latest_value  (cost=0.00..74.04 rows=2004 width=71) (actual time=0.016..0.915 rows=2004 loops=1)
        ->  Index Scan using asset_pkey on asset  (cost=0.28..7.50 rows=1 width=1508) (actual time=0.017..0.017 rows=1 loops=50)
              Index Cond: (id = latest_value.asset)
  ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.56..11519.59 rows=131 width=54) (actual time=26.169..26.169 rows=0 loops=50)
        Group Key: value_aggregation_hour.asset
        ->  Index Scan using value_aggregation_hour_pkey on value_aggregation_hour  (cost=0.56..11516.32 rows=131 width=203) (actual time=18.780..26.105 rows=50 loops=50)
              Index Cond: ((context = 'hour'::aggregation_context) AND (\"timestamp\" > '1597926623087'::bigint) AND (asset = latest_value.asset))
Planning Time: 1.066 ms
Execution Time: 1320.452 ms
```

Big improvement, would work well. But this is still not as good as using the BRIN index in the initial query.

Comment: Did you try a B-Tree index on `value_aggregation (timestamp)`?  (Btw: I find it highly confusing that a column named `timestamp` isn't defined as a `timestamp`)

Comment: Did try a b-tree, did not get used as well. Turning off seqscan there resulted in a query plan with execution time of around 2300ms, which is why I decided to use the BRIN
(it's a unix timestamp and gets used across services, that's the reason for the name)

Comment: As far as I can tell, the condition `asset in (select ... from base_table)` is useless as the same is achieved with the join condition on the derived table. What happens if your remove that IN condition from the inner query? Or maybe change that into a lateral join: https://pastebin.com/5AbH1CPe

Comment: replied with 2 updates to your comment, so that I could include the query plans

Comment: I must be missing something: "SELECT asset, timestamp, market_cap, price FROM latest_value ORDER BY market_cap_rank DESC" while there is no market_cap_rank in table latest_value.  How does that work?

Comment: emitted unnecessary columns, must've slipped that one, gonna fix in an edit right now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PostgreSQL estimates the sequential scan on `value_aggregation_hour` slightly cheaper than the index scan (233000 vs. 236000), while in reality it is much cheaper.

The row count estimate is very good, so the problem is probably that PostgreSQL has a wrong idea about your machine. You could try to improve that:

- set `effective_cache_size` to the amount of memory available for caching data (`shared_buffers` + file system cache).

  Higher values lower the estimated. cost of index scans.
- set `random_page_cost` to a lower value. If random access is as fast as sequential access on your storage system, use a value of 1.

  Lower values lower the estimated. cost of index scans.